# Count how may dates within a list are between two dates in a dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, datetime

I have a dataframe, df with two date columns and a list of dates and I'm trying to determine how many times dates within the list fall between dates in the two dataframe columns.

df:

```
Date1       Date2
2022-09-01  2022-09-07
2022-09-10  2022-09-22
2022-09-06  2022-09-21
2022-09-17  2022-09-25
2022-06-30  2022-09-21
```

list = [2022-09-16, 2022-07-01]

Here's what I would like!

df2:

```
Date1       Date2        Count
2022-09-01  2022-09-07   0
2022-09-10  2022-09-22   1
2022-09-06  2022-09-21   1
2022-09-17  2022-09-25   0
2022-06-30  2022-09-21   2
```

Comment: What did you try so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create series out of the date list, then for each row in the dataframe, call between on the series passing unpacked row values, then finally call `sum` for `axis=1`:

```py
>>> list_ = pd.to_datetime(['2022-09-16', '2022-07-01']).to_series()
>>> df['Count'] = df.apply(lambda x: list_.between(*x), axis=1).sum(1)
```

**OUTPUT**

```py
       Date1      Date2  Count
0 2022-09-01 2022-09-07      0
1 2022-09-10 2022-09-22      1
2 2022-09-06 2022-09-21      1
3 2022-09-17 2022-09-25      0
4 2022-06-30 2022-09-21      2
```